# Define special html files django

Tags: python, django

I'm beginning to use The Django Framework and I'm reading lots of tutorials but I get a problem and I would like some explanations to solve it.

My project is named : `Etat_civil`
My first app is named : `BirthCertificate`

I have the `views.py` file in `BirthCertificate App` :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def BirthCertificateAccueil(request) :
    # Fonction permettant de créer la page d'accueil de la rubrique Acte de Naissance 

    text = """ <h2 align="center"> Vous êtes actuellement dans la partie : Acte de naissance </align> </h2>

    <p> Vous souhaitez : </p>
    <p> </p>
    <p> *   Créer un acte de naissance </p>
    <p> *   Consulter un acte de naissance </p>
    <p> *   Modifier un acte de naissance </p>
    <p> *   Supprimer un acte de naissance </p> """

    return HttpResponse(text)


def BirthCertificateCreationAccueil(request) :
     # Fonction permettant de créer la page de création du formulaire de la partie : Acte de Naissance 

    text = """ <h2 align="center"> Vous allez désormais pouvoir créer un formulaire d'acte de naissance </align> </h2> """

    return HttpResponse(text)
```

**My question is :**

I must have to create a templates directory in order to put some .html files and call this files into my functions. 
Where I have to create the template directory ? I need to modify the settings.py file ?

Thank you by advance !

Comment: It is all explained in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/ .

Comment: I already read the doc, if I ask this question, it's because I spent 3 hours without to get any result.

Comment: Ok, it works, I found the process and I will put the solution in my edited post. Thank you

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer, instead of including it in your question. It makes it easier to see that you've solved your problem.

Comment: Ok no problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***SOLUTION :***

From the doc given by Klaus D. I created a templates directory in my app directory (BirthCertificate) with html files and I called this files in my functions as :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

# Create your views here.

def BirthCertificateAccueil(request) :
    # Fonction permettant de créer la page d'accueil de la rubrique Acte de Naissance 

    template = loader.get_template('accueil.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request))


def BirthCertificateCreationAccueil(request) :
     # Fonction permettant de créer la page de création du formulaire de la partie : Acte de Naissance 

     template = loader.get_template('creation_accueil.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request))
```